# Microsoft Rights to Transcription -Cogntive Speech to Text

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

My understanding is that any wav file to be transcribed should be deposited in Blob storage.  Does Microsoft have any rights to this recording or subsequent transcription?  The content of these audio files may be confidential and I have some concerns over access to this.

Allen

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a start for an answer, from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/faq-stt

> > > Question: Are my requests logged?
> > >       Answer: You have a choice during the creation of a deployment to switch off tracing, at which point no audio or transcriptions will be logged. Otherwise requests are typically logged in Azure in secure storage. If you have further privacy concerns that prohibit you from using the Custom Speech Service, contact one of the support channels